# iPhone css hover

Tags: ios, iphone, css, hover, user-agent

I have a website which shows some information on hovering over an image it works fine in every device except iphone i need to keep on pressing the screen till the hover completes the transition. i need it to work under single tap it should show the information.Here is the code 
i used for the website hover transition.

```
               { -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all .5s  ease-in-out 0.5s;
         -o-transition: all .5s  ease-in-out 0.5s;
         -ms-transition: all .5s  ease-in-out 0.5s;
         transition: all .5s  ease-in-out 0.5s; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to hover on iPhone because there is only pressed, and not pressed. There is no mouse to hover over the object, therefore it does not see it.